# Should updated timestamp be changed for PUT call with same data?

Tags: rest, http, api-design

We have a Restful API. In the response of the PUT API, we update the updated timestamp column in the database with the current time and return its value as part "updated" timestamp field in the json response.

My question is if none of the fields in the entity are updated in the PUT call, should the updated timestamp be changed or not?

To elaborate, when performing the same PUT call multiple times, without change in the entity data, should the updated timestamp change?

Are there any best practices?

Comment: As you end up with the same state after a `PUT` ,no matter how many times you trigger it, is said to be "equally potent" i.e  every time - idempotent. Agreeing with @felipe-zavan , there is no point in updating the timestamp if your `PUT` call is just the same  Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTTP spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) specifies that a `PUT` request **should** receive a *complete* representation of the resource and either create it if it doesn't exist (and respond with status `201 Created` and empty body), or *completely replace it* if it does exist (and respond with `200 OK` or `204 No Content` status and empty body). That's (almost) all. Most APIs of course ignore the "no body should be returned" part.

The "updated" timestamp should not be treated as part of the resource, but rather as metadata about the resource, and updating it should be considered a side-effect of the request, which is out of scope of the spec and so you can treat it however you think is appropriate for your use case.

In my opinion it should NOT be updated because these timestamps are usually used for caching purposes, and since the resource has not been changed there's no reason to invalidate any cache (also keep in mind that `PUT` requests are not cacheable at all according to the spec). Another use case for the timestamp would be to show final users when the resource last changed, and in that case it would make no sense to update the timestamp if nothing has changed, it would just confuse users.

As an example, Ruby on Rails does not update the `updated_at` timestamp if no attributes of the model changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that update date should reflect what actually happened.
If you actually updated the record (e.g. performed real database UPDATE call), then change the timestamp.
If you didn't actually do anything (e.g. just compared values and did nothing), then do NOT change update date. It would save you plenty of time if requests you're considered identical were actually not.
Also, as mentioned above, returning updated timestamps is not fully semantically correct, better use headers (`Last-Modified` for instance).